# Creating SFTP or FTP user account through c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ftp, sftp

Is this possible to create sftp users by my code? I'm using bitvise SSH server as my sftp server, and filezilla server as my ftp server, now I want to create different users for my different customers so that they all would have access of different folders on my server and could not be able to access each others path (folders). 
  I can use either of them (sftp or ftp), but my priority is sftp. Can anyone have some idea of user creation either in sftp or in ftp by c# code?

Comment: Seems like your server is [scriptable](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-guide-scriptable), did you try anything so far?

Comment: @nvoigt No I did not find any useful working solution for my requirement. I'm still searching for it.

Comment: @rufanov That means I'll have to create different windows account in order to create different user accounts(virtual account in bitvise ssh server) for sftp?

Comment: Virtual accounts in Bitvise server do not need backing Windows account. That's what virtual accounts are about.

Answer (score 1):

For FileZilla server, you can modify `C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml` (`FileZillaServer/Users`) and have the server reload the config using:

```
"FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config
```

Comment: This is what I done in order to reload config file:                `string fileZillaPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server";`   ` System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C " + fileZillaPath + "\\\"FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");`

Comment: This is how we reload the file, right? But this is not working and I did not see any user in filezilla server.

Comment: I'd say you are missing double-quotes around the path to the executable (as per my example). Note that there are spaces in both the path and executable name.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and here I'm posting it. It would be helpful for someone else in future:

```
try
{
    string hely = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml";
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(hely, false);
    wr.WriteLine("<FileZillaServer>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Settings>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Item name=\"Admin port\" type=\"numeric\">14147</Item>");
    wr.WriteLine("   </Settings>");
    wr.WriteLine("  <Groups />");
    wr.WriteLine("  <Users>");
    wr.WriteLine(" <User Name=\"test\">");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Pass\">test</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"Group\"></Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Bypass server userlimit\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"User Limit\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"IP Limit\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("     <Option Name=\"Enabled\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Comments\">test</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"ForceSsl\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("   <IpFilter>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Disallowed />");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Allowed />");
    wr.WriteLine("  </IpFilter>");
    wr.WriteLine("  <Permissions>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Permission Dir=\"D:\\FTP_Root\">");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"FileRead\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("     <Option Name=\"FileWrite\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"FileDelete\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"FileAppend\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"DirCreate\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirDelete\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirList\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirSubdirs\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"IsHome\">1</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"AutoCreate\">0</Option>");
    wr.WriteLine("    </Permission>");
    wr.WriteLine("  </Permissions>");
    wr.WriteLine("<SpeedLimits DlType=\"0\" DlLimit=\"10\" ServerDlLimitBypass=\"0\" UlType=\"0\" UlLimit=\"10\" ServerUlLimitBypass=\"0\">");
    wr.WriteLine("              <Download />");
    wr.WriteLine("          <Upload />");
    wr.WriteLine("       </SpeedLimits>");
    wr.WriteLine(" </User>");
    wr.WriteLine("  </Users>");
    wr.WriteLine("</FileZillaServer>");
    wr.Close();
    string pathtofilezilla = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server";
    Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"" + pathtofilezilla + "\\FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: This just overwrites complete configuration, removing all other accounts that existed before.

Comment: This is only the concept I mentioned, you'll have to parse/serialize this xml file to create new <User> node.

Comment: @ShilpaSoni : and what about SFTP...?